# How to flatten serialized data with only 1 field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following serializer:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "profile_picture")

class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    some_user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = UserFollowing
        fields = ("some_user",)
```

And the model `UserFollowing` associated to it:

```py
class UserFollowing(models.Model):
    some_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The serializer returns something like this:

```json
[
    {
        "some_user": {
            "username": "jane",
            "profile_picture": "/media/picture.jpg"
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

For consistency and simplicity, I would like to return:

```json
[
    {
        "username": "jane",
        "profile_picture": "/media/picture.jpg"
    },
    ...
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`serializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    profile_picture = serializers.SerializeMethodField()

    def get_username(self, obj):
        return obj.some_user.username
    
    def get_profile_picture(self, obj):
        return obj.some_user.profile_picture

    class Meta:
        model = UserFollowing
        fields = ("username", "profile_picture")
```